# Quotes and HandlInst <21> field in FIX protocol

Tags: fix-protocol

I'm trying to understand the variety of message types and data fields in FIX protocol.

I did understand most of the things but I'm still not sure about Quotes and HandlInst.

1. When a dealer or a broker wants to trade in the market he have a list of all available products (e.g USD/EUR, USD/JPN, ...). each product has sell-price and buy-price which being update in high rate. Which message type generates this values? A Quote message type(quote request and quote response)?
2. A broker have the option to decide for each one of his dealers whether he automatically response as the counter-party for the dealer orders or the orders go out to the market for a trade. Which filed in the order message types indicates that mark? I was thinking about HandlInst <21> but i'm not quite sure...

Thanks for your help

Comment: These are general FIX protocol questions, not specific to any engine implementation.  I removed the QuickFIX tags from your question.

Answer (score 2):

These are vendor-specific questions.  FIX just gives you a pile of messages and fields you can use, and some recommendations for how to use them.  Some counterparties even follow those recommendations, but nearly all of them add their own weird customizations or use certain fields in weird ways.

If you are connecting to an external counterparty, you need to read *their* docs for their specific FIX interface.  That will tell you which fields they use, how they use them, and what they expect from you.

So, get your counterparty's docs and read them.

Comment: Client=Initiator, Server=Acceptor.  If you are the Initiator, you need to read the counterparty's docs and build/configure your Initiator accordingly.  If you are the server, you need to publish some docs so that clients can know what they are expected to do.  (Sorry, I don't know anything about MetaTrader 4.)

Comment: Why did you delete the comment that I replied to?

Comment: I would really be glad if you can explain me in details the meaning of HandlInst including its poxxible values. And one more thing: An initiator and an acceptor can open a session between them if they both know each other compId. But what happens if i want to allow every initiator to create s session with my acceptor and accept/reject them by other terms(e.g user credentials..)? how can i configure my acceptor so that he can open a session with every initiator? (this question is more related to quickfix)

Comment: I don't know about HandlInst; instructions for this tag should be in your counterparty's spec.  I've never implemented an Acceptor that allowed unknown Initiators to connect.  Sorry I am not more helpful for your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Kitsune, here are my answers for you (you should pay me for this !)

1. yes, Quote, and QuoteCancel (usually)
2. I think you are talking about an internal broker decision that's not to do with FIX. HandlInst can be used by a client sending their order to the broker to specify manual or automatic execution, but I think that is in specific limit order cases only, not the usual fill or kill stuff. If the order was $100mio then maybe a client would specify manual execution. Again, as in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302325/which-field-define-if-the-order-is-in-a-book-or-in-b-book), the ExecutionReport can specify manual or auto execution as well. Need to look at that...

Comment: OK so I understand that HandlInst is not my answer but I still have to find the right field so... As I mentioned in my question (or in my second post), I'm writing an acceptor for the fix protocol. This acceptor will receive orders from brokers and will make an execution decision upon that mysterious fieild. According to this field I will be able to decide whether the order that the broker sent to my acceptor is in B-book, and therefore the broker is acts as a counter party and I should automatically execute the trade or is in a-book and it means that the trade should be manually executed

Comment: Whenever there is an available counter party in my db. If I'm right,  an initiator sends a new single order request to an acceptor. When a trade is being made,  the acceptor will return an execution report to the initiators of the trade's parties. So I thought that the field that tell me if the order should be filled automatically or not should be in the new single order request. I consulted with a few peoples who have a connection to this world of trading and they told me that the field AccountType might indicates what I'm looking for,  when the value 1 is b book and 2 is a book.  You think?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make an execution decision only based on who the counterparty is. When you know the cpty is a broker then you can execute automatically, but when you don't know the cpty you need to do KYC checks and have to execute manually. Hmmm. That's only the first part of the decision process. Usually you always go auto unless there's an exception, for example, counterparty type as you say, but what if the order is super large for auto? You've got to check that as well. What about a currency instrument that has specific rules or is NDF? What about value dates on holidays?

Comment: So essentially, there's a whole set of things on an order that you've got to validate. However, for cpty type I think your people are right. The AccountType could work. Or you could also use tag 1: Account and have a list of accounts for auto, and a list for manual. I don't know how you're doing your accounting :-) You've also got ExecInst, but I think what you're looking for is the Parties repeating group. PartyID, PartyIDSource or PartyRole,