# Which field define if the Order is in A-book or in B-book

Tags: fix-protocol

I'm building a FIX acceptor and in when i process a new order i want to act to different depends if the order is in A-Book or in B-Book. I can't understand qhich field may give me this information. I was thinking about HandlIndt (21) but i'm not quite sure. Anyway i would like to get a better explanation on each value of HandlInst..

Answer (score 0):

[Fiximate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/) is your friend for all these sorts of questions.

Comment: Yeah, well. i know FIXimate...but there are so many fields in one message and i don't understand all of them I'm looking for one field that tells whether an order is auto-filled by the broker, means the broker himself is the counter party (B-book) or is get into the market and wait for a counter-party(A-book) . Which filed NewOrderSingle message indiactes that?

Comment: Then I think you are confusing orders with trades. If the order is filled (either by broker or other counterparty) then you get ExecutionReport. Basically, if you don't get an ExecutionReport then your order is not filled....... Now the field in ExecutionReport that you may be looking for is something like 39 OrderStatus http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/en/FIX.5.0SP2/tag39.html

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with standard FIX itself. You should refer to your's counterparty FIX specification. If you can share ECN name, I can try to point you to the right direction.

Comment: It's a problem because I am building this not as a trader but for a new tradable product that will soon be coming to market. All of the orders will be going through our system. Some orders will be filled automatically by the broker where the investor's account is located. Some orders will be matched with other orders coming into our system. In essence, we are the ECN